# hide output of command while using cat and tee

Tags: io-redirection, cat, tee

I have a text file that contains some IPs. I want to copy the contents of this text file into `/etc/ansible/hosts` without showing the output on the terminal (as shown in example 2).

**Note:** root user is disabled.

If I use the following:

1. `sudo cat myfile.txt >> /etc/ansible/host`

It will not work, since sudo cat didn't affect redirections (expected).

2. `cat myfile.txt | sudo tee --append /etc/ansible/hosts`

It will show the output in the terminal then copy them to /etc/ansible/hosts
       A.A.A.A
       B.B.B.B
       C.C.C.C

3. Adding `/dev/null` will interrupt the result (nothing will be copied to `/etc/ansible/hosts`).

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/504343/alternative-to-the-tee-command-without-stdout

Answer (score 32, accepted):

```
sudo tee -a /etc/ansible/hosts <myfile.txt >/dev/null
```

Or, if you want to use `cat`:

```
cat myfile.txt | sudo tee -a /etc/ansible/hosts >/dev/null
```

Either of these should work.  It is unclear how you "added" `/dev/null` when you tried, but this redirects the standard output of `tee` to `/dev/null`.

Comment: Thanks, I found the problem with my code, after reading cat methods from your answer, it was an extra character :sweat_smile: that's why when I add `/dev/null` to my second command did not work.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use bash with "-c" switch.
For example:

```
sudo bash -c "cat /etc/hosts >> /etc/ansible/hosts" >> /dev/null
```